# Not able to upgrade jenkins to the latest version

Tags: jenkins

Am running Jenkins 1.6.43 in its own container in Linux. I want to upgrade to latest 2.7 version. The release notes say that all I have to do is download the latest Jenkins, remove the pinned plugins and restart.

I did the same- Stopped current jenkins,downloaded using wget, removed all pinned plugins and then started it. I get `"started jenkins - ok"`, but nothing is happening. I do not see any process running! I tried this with 2.6 and 2.7 version and I see the same result! If I revert to my previous 1.643 war and restart also, I do not see any process running.

The log shows:

```
SEVERE: Container startup failed
java.io.IOException: Failed to start a listener: winstone.Ajp13ConnectorFactory
        at winstone.Launcher.spawnListener(Launcher.java:207)
        at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:148)
        at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at Main._main(Main.java:246)
        at Main.main(Main.java:91)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: AJP support is removed in Winstone 3.0 due to Jetty 9 not supporting AJP. For reverse proxying, please use HTTP instead of AJP.
        at winstone.Ajp13ConnectorFactory.start(Ajp13ConnectorFactory.java:31)
        at winstone.Launcher.spawnListener(Launcher.java:205)
        ... 8 more

Running from: /usr/lib/jenkins/jenkins.war
Jun 05, 2016 3:17:25 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog info
INFO: Logging initialized @930ms
Jun 05, 2016 3:17:25 PM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: Beginning extraction from war file
Jun 05, 2016 3:17:25 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog warn
WARNING: Empty contextPath
Jun 05, 2016 3:17:25 PM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: Winstone shutdown successfully
Jun 05, 2016 3:17:25 PM winstone.Logger logInternal
SEVERE: Container startup failed
java.io.IOException: Failed to start a listener: winstone.Ajp13ConnectorFactory
        at winstone.Launcher.spawnListener(Launcher.java:207)
        at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:148)
        at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at Main._main(Main.java:246)
        at Main.main(Main.java:91)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: AJP support is removed in Winstone 3.0 due to Jetty 9 not supporting AJP. For reverse proxying, please use HTTP instead of AJP.
        at winstone.Ajp13ConnectorFactory.start(Ajp13ConnectorFactory.java:31)
        at winstone.Launcher.spawnListener(Launcher.java:205)
        ... 8 more
```

Can someone please help!!!How to fix this?

Comment: Setting JENKINS_AJP_PORT="-1" in /etc/sysconfig/jenkins solved problem and I could start Jenkins successfully and log in but there are other severe errors in log file

Answer (score 0):

This helped me to solve this issue 
setting up JENKINS_AJP_PORT="-1" in /etc/sysconfig/jenkins and then I restarted